# What data structure to use to store values created in a function python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, data-structures

I have a function that iterates over data with 2 loops, performs calculation, and at each iteration of the first loop i get 3 values i'd like to keep in a data structure, preferably with data frame. So at the end of the first loop I have 3 values, and at the end of the second loop, I should get a lot of rows, each row has 3 values. example below for first 3 rows:

```
   col_idx  value  score
0        0    2.4    5.5
1        0   10.1    150
2        0    1.9    8.8
```

What is the best data structure to do that?
I tried to append list of those 3 values, to one bigger list (and convert it to data frame later on), but couldn't do it. here's my code sample:

```
def calc(self):
    values = self.get_threshold_values()

    bigger_data = []

    for col_idx in range(len(self.data_set.columns)):

        score = 0.5
        value_to_split = 0
        small_data = []
        for j in range(len(threshold_values)):
            value = threshold_values.iloc[j][col_idx]  
            below_value, above_value = self.split_data(col_idx, value)
            score_for_value = self.calc_score(below_value, above_value)
            if score_for_value < score:
                score = score_for_value
                value_to_split = value
                small_data.append([col_idx, value_to_split, score])
        bigger_data.append(small_data)

    return bigger_data
```

I also thought to initialize numpy array, then to turn it to data frame.

Any ideas to do it fast and efficient?

Comment: pd.DataFrame(bigger_data) ?

Comment: `but couldn't do it` - that's not very helpful.  Appending to a list is a good way of growing a structure.  So what was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: That is the error I get: `ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')`. Actually it gives me that error even when i try just to add the 3 values to the small list. Any idea how to append 3 values at a time to a list?

Comment: you can use : small_data.extend([col_idx, value_to_split, score])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
import random 
import pandas as pd

res = {'col_idx': list() , 'value': list() , 'score' : list()}
for _ in range(5):
    small_data = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(3)]
    for i, k in enumerate(res):
        res[k].append(small_data[i])

print(pd.DataFrame(res))
```

Output sample

```
   col_idx  value  score
0        5      9      8
1        8     10      6
2        6      5      6
3        9      9      4
4        6     10      9
```

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
small_data.append([col_idx, value_to_split, score])
```

your small_data becomes a list of list like [[data1, data2...]] but you need a plain list . try:

```
small_data.extend([col_idx, value_to_split, score])
```

this will make : [data1, data2...]